# How can I attach a database to azure devops hosted agents localdb instance

Tags: azure, azure-devops, file-permissions, localdb, mdf

I try to attach a database to an instance of the localdb server running on the azure-devops agent running the windows-latest image.

Attaching the database fails with the message

> Database 'Testdatabase' cannot be upgraded because it is read-only, has read-only files or the user does not have permissions to modify some of the files. Make the database or files writeable, and rerun recovery.

Running the same thing on my local machine succeeds.

I tried setting the file permissions of the mdf and ldf I'm trying to attach to full control for `BUILTIN/everyone`, but that fails with the message

> Some or all identity references could not be translated

How can I attach my mdf to a localdb instance on the azure-devops hosted agent running the `windows-latest` image?

Comment: Choco install LocalDB ?

Comment: @ErikEJ there is a localdb already running on the agent -- otherwise I wouldn't be able to connect to it and send it the (failing) with a create database statement. Would creating another localdb service from chocolatey make a difference?

Comment: It is a newer version...

Comment: Maybe consider ceating the database on the fly with a database project instead?

Comment: @ErikEJ `Choco install LocalDB` didn't make any observable difference so far. I'm not sure what it did exactly, and whether it installed a different version of LocalDB, and if it did, if it was started, and if not, how to do that still. I guess I'll have to go shave that yak then.

Comment: @ErikEJ for some integration tests, I want to repeatedly attach/remove a database with a known state in setup/tear down of each test, and I figured just attaching the file would be the simplest and cleanest way to do that. I'm not entirely sure what a database project is, but I can look in to it. Would it be suitable for such a task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set file permissions to writable for `BUILTIN\Users` for both mdf and ldf, and database creation will succeed.